# Animate a sequence of bitmap-like data Mathematica 9.0.0

Tags: list-manipulation, animation

I am new to Mathematica, but already find it a very nice tool. Right now I am trying to create an animation of numeric data, where each frame corresponds to a distinct text file with a table-like content.

With one static frame (file) I can do the following:

```
file = "Desktop/d1.txt"
data = Import[file, "Table"]
ArrayPlot[data]
```

Now, with multiple frames (files) I have to somehow animate a list of 2D lists, e.g.:

```
files = { "Desktop/d1.txt", "Desktop/d2.txt", "Desktop/d3.txt" }
data = Map[Import[#] &, files]
```

ListAnimate is said to accept a list:

```
ListAnimate[data]
```

,but it does not display the bitmap and shows a box with an advancing position bar and text representation of the data[[1]] . I would like to playback all the files' content as consecutive bitmaps. Should I somehow rearrange my 2D lists and/or may be ListAnimate is the wrong function for that task and I should use something else?

Comment: 1) `ListAnimate` 2) there is no `ArrayPlot` in AnimateList/ListAnimate. So is `ListAnimate[ArrayPlot/@data]`  what you need?

Comment: I am sorry for the typo, indeed it is ``ListAnimate''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that does work, like Kuba says you have to give `ListAnimate` a list of exactly the elements you want to cycle through.

```
ListAnimate[Table[ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]], {i, 100}], 10]
```

[image: arrayplot]

In your case:

```
ListAnimate[Map[ArrayPlot[Import[#,"Table"]] &, files]]
```

Observe that the real name of the function is `ListAnimate` and not `AnimateList`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this is with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[ArrayPlot[RandomReal[i, {5, 5}]], {i, 1, 100}]
```

This creates a slider that allows you to move through the various images. By clicking on the small `+` sign in the upper right you can choose autorun, and it will animate through the various data.

[image]